# UWP C# | Как симулировать (вызвать) нажатие на кнопку?

Tags: c#, события, uwp

Представим что у меня есть кнопка. В моем случае мне нужно в другой функции сделать нажатие по этой кнопки.
Есть идеи по реализации?

[image: Кнопка]

Comment: Интерфейс `ICommand` вам может с этим помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button1_Click(null, null);
```

или

```
Button1_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
```

Comment: Я так и делаю сейчас. Но вызов функции не делает нажатия по обьекту

Answer (score 1):

Я использую в таких случаях

```
typeof(ButtonBase).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(button, new object[0]);
```

срабатывает для всех случаев